# Get WooCommerce order with specific status using Python

Tags: python, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm working on an interface to exchange data between our OMS and WooCommerce using the Python WooCommere API Wrapper and I'm having trouble getting orders based on status. I can get *all* of the orders like this

```
tmp_orders = DIVISION_API.get('orders')
```

but I'm trying to get only the orders with the status of 'processing'. Based on the API documentation and the json results from the order data I get with the above call, it looks like I should be able to call

```
tmp_orders = DIVISION_API.get('orders', status='processing')
```

and only get the orders that are in the processing state, but when I try this I get the error `TypeError: request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'status'`.

I've looked for solid examples using Python but can't find any solution. Any suggestions would be fantastic.

Thanks.

Comment: Doc here - https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?python#introduction

Comment: @mujuonly That’s the documentation I’ve been working with, but I can’t find any example of how to get orders based on status. It’s easy enough to get by ID `.get('orders/<id>')` , but I can’t find anything about status. It seems odd not to have any examples for filtering based on anything other than ID.

Answer (score 2):

I think I managed to figure it out. After spending quite a bit of time searching and trial and error, this looks like a workable solution.

```
orders = api_obj.get('orders', params={'per_page': 10, 'status': 'processing', 'page': 1})
```

It appears that you can pass a `dict` of parameters (as `params`) and it gets passed to the underlying request. I don't know if that's the way that the API wrapper developer intended it to be used, but it works reliably. Hope this will help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with that API, but from what the documentation states you should perform the `.get('orders')`, use `.json()` on the response to get the info in `json` format and then you can search for orders that have the key `status` equal to `processing`.

Comment: That's actually what I've been doing during the testing phase, but I was hoping there was a better way. I could see this method getting expensive as the number of orders increase. Most Python API wrappers support passing arguments to the request as kwargs that are parsed and used to filter the REST call. This would also be helpful for pagination, etc. I do appreciate your suggestion though!